# Транспонирование в Firebird

Tags: firebird

У меня есть таблицы клиента, и его контактных данных вида:

```
adresse
adresseid, name, etc..
```

```
kommunication
adresseid, komm_artid, komm_text
1,         telefon,    +123456
1,         handy,      12346
1,         email,      any@example.com
```

И я хочу получить эти данные в одну строку.
Но, не могу использовать LIST, возникают проблемы.

Существуют ли средства в Firebird для получения результата вида:

adresseid, field_1...field_N

без ручного копипаста для неизвестного количества полей..

База Read-only.

Есть аналог в MSSQL:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
               C.name <> 'color'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT  ',' 
                      + quotename(color)
                    from yourtable t
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
  = 'select name, '+@colsPivot+'
      from
      (
        select color, name, value
        from yourtable
        unpivot
        (
          value for name in ('+@colsUnpivot+')
        ) unpiv
      ) src
      pivot
      (
        sum(value)
        for color in ('+@colsPivot+')
      ) piv'

exec(@query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть стандартная практика для эмуляции PIVOT в СУБД его не поддерживающих - разворот CASE'ом.

```
SELECT
  A.adresseid, A.name, A.etc...
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN K.komm_artid = 'telefon' THEN K.komm_text END) AS "telefon"
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN K.komm_artid = 'handy' THEN K.komm_text END) AS "handy"
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN K.komm_artid = 'email' THEN K.komm_text END) AS "email"
  ...
FROM adresse A
LEFT JOIN kommunication K ON K.adresseid = A.adresseid
GROUP BY A.adresseid, A.name, A.etc...
```

Так как строки CASE почти одинаковые их можно сгенерировать SQL-запросом

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  'MAX(CASE WHEN K.komm_artid = '''||K.komm_artid||''' THEN K.komm_text END) AS "'||K.komm_artid||'"'
FROM kommunication K
```

PS если внимательно посмотреть со всех сторон на выполнение PIVOT в MSSQL, то становится понятно, что внутри там ровно такой же разворот CASE'ом.

Comment: Благодарю, полдела есть..
 Остаётся вторая часть, я непонимаю даже как ms работает конструкция for xml, для получения результата в переменную, как это можно реализовать в Firebird?
К тому же, там же два синтаксиса, и set недопустим в запросе, только в хранимке. А база ридонли. Но это мелочи, можно генерить запрос снаружи.

Comment: Хотя, можно же select list(select distinct from komm)

Comment: в данном случае FOR XML - это извращенный способ реализовать агрегат LIST при отсутствии оного в MSSQL, путем сначала конвертации выборки в XML, а затем выдирания из его данных.